# Azure Create Container

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

After creating an Azure Storage account using Python SDK when proceeding to create a storage blob container its throws the following error :
`ResourceNotFound`The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:508e8df1-301e-004b-224e-c5feb1000000
Time:2018-03-26T22:03:46.0941011Z

Code snippet:

```
def create_blob_container(self, storage_account_name, storage_account_key, version):
    try:
        account = BlockBlobService(account_name = storage_account_name, account_key = storage_account_key.value)          
        container_name = "dummy container"
        container = account.create_container(container_name)
        if container:
            print 'Container %s created' %(container_name)
        else:
            print 'Container %s exists' %(container_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Does anybody have any idea how to go about this?

P.S.: I am waiting for provisioning state of storage account to be succeeded and then proceeding to create a container.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any space in your container name ? I don't think space are allowed in container name.

Comment: [Container names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#container-names) must be all lowercase, no spaces and no longer than 63 characters. Check if all this is true in your case.

Comment: Also storage account names have [similar restrictions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2014/06/12/azure-storage-naming-rules/) and must be between 3 and 24 characters and globally unique. I.e. if somebody already taken "mystorage" - you won't be able to create the same account

Comment: container name and storage account names both are valid. @Thomas

Comment: which version of the puthon sdk are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spoke with Microsoft Azure team, apparently they are facing network related issues with storage accounts. For me, its failing all the time when I try to create a container, but for one of my colleague, he is getting mixed results; sometimes it goes through in 15seconds, sometimes it takes upto 10 minutes and most of the times it is bailing out.

That might be what’s going on- they’ll get back to us tomorrow with an update.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as @Thomas and @trailmax mentioned in the comment that the container name and blob name need to follow [naming rules](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2014/06/12/azure-storage-naming-rules/). The `"dummy container"` in your sample code is inconsistent with the rules certainly. It will throw exception ：

> azure.common.AzureHttpError: The specifed resource name contains
>   invalid characters.ErrorCode: InvalidResourceName

Then I test your code and it works well for me.

```
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlockBlobService,
    ContainerPermissions,
)

accountName = "***"
accountKey = "***"
containerName = "test"

account = BlockBlobService(account_name = accountName, account_key = accountKey)
container = account.create_container(containerName)
if container:
    print 'Container %s created' %(containerName)
else:
        print 'Container %s exists' %(containerName)
```

I suggest you check if your `request client` has permission to create resources in the storage account. If no permission of creation, above exception will be thrown.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
The container name - "Dummy container" was a sample that I gave, infact the actual container name that I am using is "1724-container". 
My request client has all the permissions. The problem is its not consistent. Once in a while it works and the other times it bails out throwing that error.